# Запрос к таблицам с соотношением Один-Ко-Многим (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

Использую БД **Postgresql**.
Есть таблица request1 (ЗАПРОСЫ), и таблица user1 (ЮЗЕРЫ). Соотношение Один-Ко-Многим, т.е. с одним запросом может быть связано несколько юзеров.

Привожу пример запроса из таблицы:

| id | active | sourceid | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REQUEST-204 | true | 1234 | ... |

И связанных с этим запросом юзеров из второй таблицы:

| request_id | status_call | department | email | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REQUEST-204 | 0 | ОЭРМ | user123@test.ru | ... |
| REQUEST-204 | 1 | СА | admin@test.ru | ... |

Далее, прежде чем записывать новые данные, я хочу проверить, что таких данных в базе ещё нет, чтобы не было дубликатов. По условию дубликаты я ищу по значениям полей sourceid (источник запроса), и email (емаилы юзеров уникальные). Причём мне надо проверить именно 2 емаила, так как эти 2 пользователя с разными ролями. То есть если у меня уже есть запись в базе с указанным источником, с которой связаны 2 указанных юзера, то новые записи я создавать не буду.

Для проверки я написал такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM request1 R

LEFT JOIN user1 U
  ON R.id = U.request_id

WHERE sourceid = '1234'
  AND email = 'user123@test.ru'
```

И получаю такой результат:

```
count
-----
    1
```

Но проблема в том, что я учитываю емаил только 1 юзера.
**Подскажите, как изменить запрос, чтобы учесть емаил обоих юзеров?**

Comment: *Причём мне надо проверить именно 2 емаила, так как эти 2 пользователя с разными ролями.* Где и в какой форме хранятся сведения, что именно эти два email должны проверяться?

Comment: @Akina  эти 2 емаила хранятся в таблице пользователей  user1

Comment: Выложите ВСЕ необходимые таблицы с примером данных. Согласно [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.